# mysqli_stmt_get_result and mysqli_fetch_all incompatible?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to bind parameters (for security) and then get the result into an array, so I created code like the following. The problem is that it doesn't work: `$arr` is null. (BTW I know the query in `getList` works.)

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "call getList(?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $userInputSearch);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    $arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $jsonArr = json_encode($arr);
    echo $jsonArr;
```

Note that I've got `mysqli_fetch_all` to work when using `mysqli_query()`.

On [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) reference, I found this comment:

> Also, mysqli_fetch_all works only for buffered result sets, which are
>   the default for mysqli_query. MYSQLI_USE_RESULT will be supported in
>   5.3.4+ However, it makes little sense to use it this way, materialising unbuffered sets. In this case choose STORE_RESULT, and
>   fetch_all won't copy the data, but reference it, as it is stored
>   already in mysqlnd.

I discovered that prepared statements return unbuffered results, so I tried using `$result = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt)` instead of `$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);` However that didn't help.

That leaves me not completely at a loss — I understand that I could loop to load the data one row at a time, but I really don't want to have to loop in PHP just to do something as simple as get an array from a prepared statement. Is there a way to acquire and deal with the result set as one object?

Comment: If memory serves you have to use the `_stmt_` functions throughout, including `mysqli_stmt_prepare`  and `stmt_init` in order for this to work properly.

Comment: This is a great example of how badly out of hand the MySQLi API has gotten as new features are added. The docs clearly say you can use an object from `mysqli_store_result()` but don't refer to `mysqli_stmt_store_result()`. I'm favoriting this question.

Answer (score 0):

I've just reread documentation...

I have no possibility to test mysql right now.

But just a guess:

> mysqli_fetch_all ( mysqli_result $result ...
>
> Parameters  result Procedural style only: A result set identifier
> returned by mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() or
> mysqli_use_result().

I want to highlight that all functions `mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() mysqli_use_result()` belongs to mysqli class, not to `stmt` and they return type `mysqli_result`

but you are trying to use `mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);`

> mysqli_result mysqli_stmt_get_result ( mysqli_stmt $stmt )
> ...
>
> Return Values
> Returns a resultset or FALSE on failure.

So this function return type `resultset` not `mysqli_result`.

So you have to change your code to use no mysqli_stmt

so change :

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "call getList(?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $userInputSearch);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query ( $con , "call getList(".mysqli_real_escape_string($userInputSearch).")" );
```

, or
just change your line:

`$arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

to

```
$arr = array()
 while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            arr[] = $row ;
        }
```

Sorry if any error, have no possibility to trace and debug right now, hope it is helpful.

Comment: From the OP's question: "That leaves me not completely at a loss — I understand that I could loop to load the data one row at a time, but **I really don't want to have to loop in PHP** just to do something as simple as get an array from a prepared statement."

Comment: Thanks, @KimAlexander. However, dealing with an escaped string in the stored procedure could be much more code, so I guess I'll have to loop. It's sad though, but I guess you get what you pay for. Maybe what I want can be done in ASP.

Comment: I don't see any  problem with new variant to call stored procedure. it is almost the same that you had before. This `mysqli_real_escape_string` just sanitize value and prepare it for the query. And I can't understand the logic to switch between asp and php cause of this reason. But you can do whatever you want . good luck anyway :-)

Comment: I'm not going to switch. I was just musing.